# Do I need old SSH keys if I migrate to a new computer to use Git?

Tags: github, ssh, ssh-keys

I am migrating all my work to a new computer.
I seem to remember having once - ages ago - generated an SSH key for Git / Github. 
Where is this key stored? Do I need to find it if I want to access the same Git repos from a new computer? Or can I simply generate new keys?

Comment: btw, that question is about ssh-authentication, and not really related to `git`; `git` only allows `ssh` based transport (among many other transports); `GitHub` (which is **not the same** as git) has only two transports, one of them being ssh with key-based authentication (the other being https)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key is stored in your home directory at `~/.ssh`. For Windows, this means `C:\Users\<username>\.ssh`. You can copy that whole directory to the new machine to keep the keys the way they are.

However, copying the keys is usually discouraged. The key in question is a private key which should stay private at all costs. Whoever has the key can communicate with GitHub or other sites on your behalf. So it’s recommend that you avoid having to copy it ever to something else (so you don’t accidentally allow others to copy it too).

Instead, you should create a new key on your new machine, add that to GitHub and remove the old one. See [this help page](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 5):

The SSH keys on your computer are likely stored in `~/.ssh` (if you are on Windows, I'm not sure). But, the good news is the SSH key isn't tied to your specific git repository. Github uses the key to grant permissions to a user (instead of a password), so you can add a new key as long as you still have your Github password.

[GitHub Help: Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!